# Local createdAt & updatedAt timestamps in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm working on getting the following frameworks together to automatically map JSON responses to Realm and save the objects to the database.

- Realm
- Alamofire
- ObjectMapper
- AlamofireObjectMapper

With this I want to set the `createdAt` (local timestamp that is not coming from the server) timestamp if it is a new object, and always update `updatedAt`. `updatedAt`is pretty straight forward to set, except for not having any triggers to sign up for and do it in a clean way.

I started by using `realm.add(object, update: true)`, but I realised this was nulling out the existing `createdAt`.

One solution is to always fetch the object before save, but that seems to be pretty heavy when fetching a lot of objects just to keep the `createdAt` intact.

1. Aren't there any triggers in Realm to subscribe to run code on
   e.g. save/load?
2. What is the best way to handle timestamps like this in Realm?

Comment: If you want to use `realm.add(object, update: true)` your object should have a primary key. Do you have that?

Comment: yep! I'm syncing data between server/client and using UUID as primary key.

Comment: Your best options seems to fetch the object by primary key, update it and trust in Realm's performance :) How many objects are you talking about when you say 'fetching a lot of objects'?

Comment: I guess maximum 100-1000, haven't tested the performance yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's been discussed in the comments is definitely the best approach. Realm won't update properties that aren't included in `object` (i.e., if it's a `Dictionary` outlining only a few properties), but if you're updating with a proper Realm `Object`, `nil` is a valid value and so there's no way for Realm to know to not touch it.

Realm's performance is fast in the fact that objects and their values aren't actually paged into memory until you actually start accessing their properties, so manually updating the objects as mentioned in the comments should work, and shouldn't have any noticeable performance overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you please add the answer to question (1) as well? It would seem like a common need to run code on save/load of objects (e.g. adding updatedAt timestamp before save)? Do you have that in the backlog or what's your thought about it?

Comment: ran into the next problem from migrating my app from CoreData to Realm: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1277. Having save triggers would make it simpler to keep an updated cached value of related objects' values.

Comment: @bdash / TiM do you have any triggers to be notified on load or save?

Comment: Are the life cycle methods requested at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1994 what you mean by triggers? If so, Realm does not yet support them.